# how to create two tables in one database

Tags: android, sqlite

Am trying to create two tables in one database in sqlite but only the first table (sharelist) is creating and second table (usedlist) is not creating.

please help me...

public class createSqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
 private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "sy_id";

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "symbol";
    public static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";    
    private static final String TAG = "createSqliteHelper";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME="tradely.db";
 private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "sharelist";


   private static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "usedlist";

private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;

 private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;



    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE=("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sharelist (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, category TEXT);");
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1=("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usedlist( sy_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, symbol TEXT, position INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (symbol) REFERENCES sharelist(_id);");






    public createSqliteHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    try {


        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE1);

    }
    catch(SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("createerr",e.toString());
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    android.util.Log.w("LunchList", "Upgrading database, which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sharelist");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usedlist");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: do you have a logcat error log? did it throw any exception?

Comment: yes. It throws like   "12-18 19:12:13.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(930): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: usedlist: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM usedlist ORDER BY symbol"

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a `)` to close the second `CREATE TABLE` statement; thus, the table is not being created and you get that error.

You have:

```
sharelist(_id);
```

And it must be:

```
sharelist(_id) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't your immediate problem, but you may need to fix this soon: You're creating a TEXT column named `symbol` in the `usedlist` table. I'm guessing, from the column name, that you plan to store the stock symbol in that column. But `symbol` is declared as a FOREIGN KEY that references a column named `_id`, which is an INTEGER, in the `sharelist` table.

It would probably be best to move `symbol` into the `sharelist` table, and create a new column in `usedlist` (say, `share_id`) to reference `sharelist`.